# How can you merge two hard drives of 4TB?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, raid, merge, spanned

Yes, I know it is not recommended (but it's only temporary) and yes, I know I would lose all my data if something happens.

But, is there any way to merge my two 4TB drives into one ? I tried with the Disk Management tool on Windows but it can't do anything ; it cannot convert to Dynamic nor create Spanned or Striped Partitions.

So, is there any way for me to make these two 4TB Hard drives only one ?

*Only one as "If I connect both on my pcs, only one letter will appear, with 7.5TB of space.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mentioned Windows. Will it be enough if a solution works in Windows? (please add the [tag:windows] tag if so). May the disks be totally wiped out? or are you hoping for a solution that allows you to keep the existing files without moving them back and forth?

Comment: Thanks Kamil for the reminder, no I don't intended it to work only on windows, but I've found the answer : Storage Space on Windows does what I want, you have to select "Simple mirroring"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer : Storage Space on Windows does what I want, you have to select "Simple mirroring"